# find out the "username" in enterprise integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

In Enterprise integrator (WSO2) server, How should I know, which application send me the requests?

I need to have application "username" and send the username in body to Endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to identify the client calling a service.

- By looking at the user agent Header.
- By looking at the Origin IP.
- Make the user add a unique identifier to the request.
- If an Auth header is sent by the client, by looking at the Auth information(e.g: If an OAuth token is sent you can do an introspect call to the Token server to get user details etc.)